# Drawing behaviour with Graphics on java

Tags: graphics, drawing, panel

I have this code:

```
public class SomeNewLayer extends JLayeredPane{

public void paintGraphics(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 250);
  }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 250);

  }
}
```

The first method, if called, draws the rectangle and in a blink of an eye it just disapears.
The second method, if called, draws the rectangle and it will then remain. Why?

I know it is supposed to override the paintComponent, but I was unable to find a hint as why the first method drawing won't remain.